# update a form from a component of another page jsf

Tags: forms, jsf-2

i have a xhtml page which sets the values of my datatable which is in another page and i want to update the datatable when i set a new object which occurs when i click in a commandbutton.

heres my page that sets value: fichas_horas.xhtml

```
<h:body>

        <f:view>
        <h:form id = "formulario">

            <h1>Medicos</h1>

            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />



           <p:dataTable id= "tabla" value="#{fichaBean.horas}" var="Grupo_horario" border="1" >

                <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                Hora
                </f:facet>
                #{fichaBean.Nombrehora(Grupo_horario)}
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                Disponibles
                </f:facet>
                #{fichaBean.disponibles(Grupo_horario.codigo)}
                </p:column>


                 <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Seleccionar</f:facet>

                     <p:commandButton id="bespecialidad" action="tipo_ficha" disabled="#{(fichaBean.bloquear(fichaBean.disponibles(Grupo_horario.codigo)))}" value ="seleccionar" >
                            <f:actionListener binding="#{fichaBean.guardar_ficha(Grupo_horario.codigo)}" /> 
                            <f:actionListener binding="#{fichaBean.cargarcolacaja()}" update=":formcolacajas" />
                       </p:commandButton>
                 </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>





        </h:form>
    </f:view>


    </h:body>
```

and this one is the datatable that i want to update: lista_espera_caja.xhtml

```
 <h:body>

        <f:view>
        <h:form id = "formcolacajas">

            <h1>Lista de espera a caja</h1>

            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"  />
            #{fichaBean.cargarcolacaja()}


           <p:dataTable id= "tabla" value="#{fichaBean.colacaja}" var="Ficha" border="1">

                <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                Turno
                </f:facet>
                #{fichaBean.nombreturno(Ficha)}
                </p:column>



            </p:dataTable>





        </h:form>
    </f:view>


    </h:body>
```

i tried to put an update=":formcolacajas" in my button but it does nothing.

Comment: Another page in another browser tab? Then this will not work at all and you need to use a 'push' mechanism (primefaces push e.g.)

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah ive tried to understand the push in primefaces without success and the best i could do is a poll that updates every 2 seconds, which is good but i tough there could be a easy way to do it in real time